# Famous ideal lattices

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, ring-lwe

I am wondering if there exist some special rings $R$ that gives us, under the canonical embedding, some special lattices, like the root lattices, Barnes-Wall lattices, Leech lattices, ...

In more details, is there some rings $R$ such that $\sigma(R)=D_n, \,  A_n, \, BW^n ...$?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are. The following table is taken from [this paper of Ducas and van Woerden](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/910.pdf), although the results are not derived there (in the below, $p$ is an odd prime, and $n, m$ are coprime).
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{2^k}]&\cong \mathbb{Z}^{2^{k-1}}\\
\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p] &\cong A_{p-1}^*\\
\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{p^k}]&\cong \bigoplus_{i = 1}^{p^k-1}\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]\cong I_{p^k\times p^k}\otimes \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]\\
\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{nm}]&\cong \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]\otimes \mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]
\end{align*}
Conway and Sloane's book *Sphere Packings, Lattices, and Groups* is the canonical reference on the topic of lattices. Chapter 8 discusses "algebraic" constructions of lattices. This means two things:

1. Constructions of lattices as $R$-modules of a certain rank for $R\neq\mathbb{Z}$
2. Constructions of lattices as ideals within (the ring of integers of) an algebraic number field

Note that these things are *slightly* different. For example, an ideal lattice has rank at most the degree of the underlying number field (as it is a sublattice of $\mathcal{O}_K$), but there is no such restriction on the first case.

Anyway, chapter 8, section 7.3 gives a general equation for the lattice $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_m]$, in particular its Gram matrix $A$ has $(j, k)$ entry:
$$A_{j, k} = \frac{\mu(d)\varphi(m)}{\varphi(d)},\quad d = \frac{m}{(m, k-j)}$$

They then summarize constructions of $E_6$ as an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_9]$,
the Leech lattice as an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_{39}]$ (note that $\varphi(39) = 24$).

There are a few other constructions given as well, but those are the "biggest names".

*Edit*:

One can further realize *Craig's Lattices* as ideals (again within the ring of integers of a cyclotomic number field).
Craig's Lattices are a family of lattices $A_n^{(m)}$ obtained by starting with $A_n^{(0)} = \mathbb{Z}^{n+1}$, and performing a "repeated differencing" operation.
I will not define the construction here, but notably:

1. $A_n^{(1)}=  A_n$ is the (primal) $A_n$ root lattice.
2. According to Conway and Sloane, Craig's lattices are the densest packings known for dimension $148 \leq n \leq 3000$. I do not know how/if this knowledge has changed in the last 20 years.

One can then obtain $A_{p-1}^{(m)}$ as the ideal $(1-\zeta_p)^m$ within the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_p]$. The minimal norm (which I believe Conway and Sloane uses to denote the *squared norm*) is not explicitly known, but can be lower-bounded (in the case that $n = p-1$, and $m < n/2$) by $2m$.
See chapter 8 section 6 of Conway and Sloane, or Proposition 5.4.7 of Martinet's *Perfect Lattices in Euclidean Space*.

Comment: Could you edit the question title? The famous is a very broad term...

Comment: @kelalaka I'm not OP, but I think their point is to be broad. They could be somewhat restrictive ("Root lattices as ideal lattices"), but this precludes lattices like the Barnes-Wall lattices which they are interested in as well. Essentially the scope of lattices they're interested in seem to be lattices that someone named + studied in other contexts that can be realized as ideal lattices, so the name makes sense.

Comment: You can edit and leave a comment to make the question's tittle fit better. This is common here.

Comment: @Mark Thanks a lot! And what about Barnes-Wall?

Comment: @C.S. You can construct it as a lattice over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, via applying construction D to Reed Muller codes, or via the action of a certain group (the clifford group) on a certain vector. You can read some about it [here](https://cp4space.hatsya.com/2020/10/10/the-barnes-wall-lattices/). I am unaware of a realization of it as an ideal lattice.

Comment: "remarkable lattices that are also ideal lattices"